# Triggering an overlay through Javascript in Plone

Tags: overlay, plone, jquery-tools

I defined my overlay for  like that

```
    $j('#heise').prepOverlay(
    {   
        subtype: 'ajax',
        noform: function(el) {return noformerrorshow(el, 'close');}
    }
```

(which is working perfectly fine).

Now I need to trigger the overlay manually.

The user enters some data into so form and upon form submission the result should be displayed inside the overflow. Modifying the 'href' value with the form parameters is no problem however I don't know how to trigger the appearance of the overlay manually through Javascript. I found the low-level overlay() API method of jqueryTools but it's not helpful here. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normal way to open a jQueryTools overlay is through `.load()` on the [overlay API](http://flowplayer.org/tools/overlay/index.html), but .prepOverlay hides all that in it's own wrapper in place for `ajax` style overlays. You can do one of two things:

1. Call the click handler:

   ```
   jQuery('#heise').click();
   ```

   This will trigger the correct handlers for all click events.
2. Call the `pb.ajax_click` handler directly, binding `this` to your element:

   ```
   pb.ajax_click.apply(jQuery('#heise'));
   ```

   This only will trigger the `ajax` click handler.

Comment: Nope - this causes a """Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'load' of undefined"""  error

Comment: @RestRisiko You are off course, correct; I didn't read far enough into the prepareOverlay method. For ajax a click handler is created that you can call. See updated answer.